# Passing GET/POST parameteres to php via commandline

Tags: php, .net, command-line

I'll excuse myself behorehand because i'm quite sure there'll be some obvious solution or an answer already out there, but after quite some extensive search I just cant find it.

I'm developing a simplified web server as a project in .net. What i want to do is calling the php.exe for each HTML request to execute any php code within the file, and then return the result to my server where it will be served to the client.

This was quite simple without passing GET/POST parameters, but I can't find the way to make this work.

Right now i have this as my function to write the call the php via command line

```
Public Shared Function phpparse(ByVal requesttype As String, ByVal argnames() As String, ByVal argvals() As String)
    Dim proc As Process = New Process
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "php\php.exe"
    Dim B As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    B.Append("-B ""$_")
    B.Append(requesttype & " = array(")
    For i As Integer = 0 To argnames.Length - 1
        B.Append("'" & argnames(i) & "' => '" & argvals(i) & "', ")
    Next
    B.Remove(B.Length - 2, 2)
    B.Append(");"" -F script.php")
    InputBox("", "", B.ToString)
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = B.ToString
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.Start()
    Return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
End Function
```

which returns something like this:

```
-B "$_GET = array('name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john.doe@no.com');" -F script.php
```

and should be calling this test php script:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

but it gets stuck trying to read the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work around the issue. I'm still looking for a proper solution but I can work with this for now

The parameters of the call to the PHP CLI should be

-r "$arrayname = array('arraypar1' => 'arrayval1', 'arraypar2' => 'arrayval2', ); require_once('C:\fullroutetofile\script.php');"

It seems that you can't call -B and -f at the same time, but require_once lets you bypass that.

Answer (score 1):

With php you could read the args like this:

```
<?php    
if (isset($argv)) {
    echo $argv[1]." ".$argv[2];
}
?>
```

this will return

> John john.doe@no.com

I don't really get it how do you send the command line params.
You should just run the php like

> php.exe John john.doe@no.com

Comment: Thanks for the input. I know I can pass arguments like that, but I'd rather find a solution that doesn't force me (or a user) to rewrite the php code. The "-B" part should create the $_GET array just like if I just passed php the whole html request, but it obviously doesn't